# routing trouble while running in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I was trying to do a project unfortunetly the router doesn't works.. Please give your kind glance of view to my code.. Can anyone gets whats the correct issue of my code.. here is my code..
routes.js page

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { LoginForm } from './components/LoginForm/LoginForm';
import { About } from './components/About/About';
import { Companies } from './components/Companies/Companies';
import { HomePage } from './components/HomePage/HomePage';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";

class Routes extends Component {
    componentDidMount(){
        alert("ok");
    }
   render() {
      return (
        <div>
       <Router> 
        <Switch>
            <Route path="/" component={HomePage}/>
            <Route path="/about" component={About}/>
            <Route path="/loginform" component={LoginForm}/>
            <Route path="/companies" component={Companies}/>

        </Switch>
      </Router>
    </div>
      );
  }
}
export default Routes;
```

& this is my homepage.js

```
class HomePage extends Component {
  componentDidMount(){
    alert("hme");
  }
   render() {
      return (
       <div className="backgrnd" >

       <h1><blink> MULTIHAND ONLINE IT WORLD</blink></h1>

       <h3 className="outside"><marquee>It's First Time In India.. New Evolution Rising Up.. Your Complete Business,Carrier & Developing Partner..</marquee></h3>
       <Router>

    <div className="banner">
        <div>
            <ul>
                <li><Link className="a" to='/'>•Home</Link></li>
                <li><Link className="a" to='/about'>•About</Link></li>     
                <li><Link className="a" to='/loginform'>•Login</Link></li>
                <li><Link className="a" to='/companies'>•Companies</Link></li>
                <li><Link className="a" to='/services'>•Services</Link></li>
                <li><Link className="a" to='/contact'>•Contact</Link></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <hr/>
        <Route path="/services" component={Services}/>
            <Route path="/contact" component={Contact}/>
    </div>
      </Router>
 </div>

    );
  }
}

const Home = () => (
  <div>
    <h2>Home</h2>
    <div className="wrapper">
    <div className="row">
    <div className="ann"><div className="blink"><span>ANNOUNCEMENTS<br></br></span></div>*New launching of IT company Martl park Solutions in Technopark Thejswani Building 2nd Floor @12.00pm on 12th May 2018</div>
    <div className="ann1"><div className="blink"><span>VACCANCIES </span></div>*No new Openings</div>
    <div className="ann2"><h3 className="blink1"><span>Today's Highest Profit Closing Company </span></h3><b>*Tata Elxsi</b>(Nearer to 2crs.)</div>
    <div className="ann3"><div className="blink"><span>EMERGING TECHNOLOGIES </span></div><div>*java</div><div>*JavaScript</div><div>*C##</div><div>*Python</div><div>*C++</div><div>*C</div></div>
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>
);




const Services = () => (
  <div>
    <h2>Services</h2>
  </div>
);

const Contact = () => (
  <div>
    <h2>Contact Us</h2>
    <h3 className="inside">MULTIHAND ONLINE IT WORLD</h3>
    <h4>Tech Arcade Building </h4>
    <h4>Inside Technopark</h4>
    <h4>Kazhakuttam P.O</h4>
    <h4> Thiruvanathapuram </h4>
    <hr/>
    <h4 className="con"> ☏:- +91-9854631278</h4>
    <h4 className="con"> ✉:- online@multihandworld.com</h4>

  </div>
);

export default HomePage;
```

Can anyone suggests any idea to route correctly to the page.. Now only i got a blank page.. I want to load homepage first..

Comment: Which version of `react-router` are you using? It'll be listed in your 'package.json'.

Comment: @RossAllen  "react-router-dom": "^4.2.2",

Comment: By the way, you might want to remove that phone number and email from your question...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're importing from **named exports** on your `Routes`, meanwhile you're using **default exports** on your actual components.

Instead of:

```
import { LoginForm } from './components/LoginForm/LoginForm';
```

Try doing this with the others as well:

```
import LoginForm from './components/LoginForm/LoginForm';
```

In my case, due to generating my project with `create-react-app`, a failure to notice this will give me an error like so:

```
148:112-120 './components/LoginForm/LoginForm' does not contain an export named 'LoginForm'.
```

Also, remove your `Router` from `homepage.js` and move the `Route`s into your `routes.js` into the `Switch` block:

```
render() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Router> 
       <Switch>
        <Route path="/" component={HomePage}/>
        <Route path="/about" component={About}/>
        <Route path="/loginform" component={LoginForm}/>
        <Route path="/companies" component={Companies}/>

        {/*Note services and contact is now in routes.js instead of homepage.js*/}
        <Route path="/services" component={Services}/>
        <Route path="/contact" component={Contact}/>
       </Switch>
     </Router>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Also make sure to import/move those components there as well.

Comment: Ya..It's works.. But there is another issue I have loginpage,companies and about.. But It doesn't route to that pages while clicking the header ,menu..

Comment: Try removing the `<Route>` tags from inside `HomePage` first and see what happens, as you can't use nested Routes anymore on v4.

Comment: then how I write the other routing pages without routing tag??

Comment: Have you tried removing all your `Route` and `Router` from `HomePage`? Anyways, you already have `Link` for navigation. If you need to add more `Route`s, you should add/move those into your `Switch` block

Comment: Updated answer. Please try again. At least, try to remove your `Router` from `HomePage` if you don't want to remove the `Route path`s

Comment: Thanks for your help.. But routing problem doesn't change.Anyways what I actually ask at first You gave me the answer..If you have time please try to help me to remove the routing issue...

Comment: You're welcome! As for the routing issue, you might need to refer to the documentations. For me, I use react-router by defining all my routes inside the `Router` and `Switch` block as I had suggested. Are you still getting blank pages though?

Comment: No,Now I get homepage.. But in homepage the navigation bars to loginpage, companies and about are doesn't work..